# The ratio of areas of two triangles with the same altitude is equal to the ratio of their bases

Tags: geometry, triangles, area

How can we prove that the ratio of areas of two triangles of equal altitudes is equal to the ratio of their bases?

Comment: What is the conventional formula for a triangle's area given its altitude h and base b?

Answer (score 2):

Very easily:

$$\frac{A_1}{A_2}=\frac{b_1h/2}{b_2h/2}=\frac{b_1}{b_2}$$

Comment: This assumes that you've already established that the area is half the base times the height.  But the proposition in the question might be a step on the way to proving that. $\qquad$